# Where to Place Master-class Certificates in Curriculum Vitae?

Tags: masters, cv, certification

I shall soon get my degree in Biochemistry. Recently I attended several professional master-classes on film-making and producing, and now I want to get a MA in Film. For this masters, my CV is needed. Thinking that the master-classes I attended will help me in my admission, I am unsure under which sub-category I should place the names of the certificates; under 'Certificates & Awards', 'Education', 'Experience', or something else?

Answer (score 1):

My $0.02-- Education appears to be the most relevant category in this instance. A master-class, unless I am mistaken, is neither a certificate nor an award, so wouldn't truly fit there. 'Experience' could certainly be a valid option also, but since you are moving from one discipline to another, it may benefit you more to be able to show some *educational* experience in film-making and producing as you apply for the Master's program.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply create a separate section for 'Masterclasses attended'? That helps them stand out, and avoids the (obvious) difficulty of deciding which other category they fit into.

Compare: academic CVs usually have sections entitled "Conference Presentations" or "Invited Seminars" or similar.